# Maven: How to make SNAPSHOT artifacts identical even if built at different times?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, maven-war-plugin, maven-jar-plugin

We use SNAPSHOTs a lot and rebuild frequently, and have found that even if the source was unchanged the resulting artifact was not binary identical to the artifact built last time.

I would like them to be.

To my understanding from a SO post I cannot find again there are two reasons they change:

- JAR/WAR/etc files are zip files with extra metadata, and each entry has a timestamp which is either "assembly time" or "compile time".
- Signed jars contain signing information, which is not sorted (i.e. the order may change between JVMs)

We do not use signed jars at the moment, and I can live with all datestamps in the JAR/WAR/etc files being 0 if that will buy me binary identity.

Apparently that means I need to get Maven Archiver to explicitly set date stamps when assembling the jar, but I cannot locate the place in the documentation where I can set this, so it most likely does not exist.  A quick look at the maven-jar-plugin and maven-war-plugin to see where the information is collected did not make me much wiser of how to change it.

My question is, how should I approach this?

Comment: Why do you rebuilt if nothing has changed in your code?

Comment: @khmarbaise "mvn clean install" tends to do that.  That is not the issue here.